# Help understanding derivatives as linear transformations

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives, linear-transformations

So I've got the following question: For every $x \in C[0,1]$ and polynomial $f(x)$, define $T_f: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ by $T_f(x)(t) = f(x(t)) $ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Also, assume the norm on $C[0,1]$ is the $||\cdot||_\infty$ norm. Show that the derivative $T'_f(x)$ of $T_f(x)$ applied to a function $y\in C[0,1]$ is $f'(x)\ y$.

I was also given a hint: Show that the derivative of $x^n$ applied to $y$ is $nx^{n-1}y$ for every $n=0,1,..$

I'm pretty new to functional analysis. Can someone just explain how, in general, one goes about proving that the derivative of a function of a function can be found or shown to be a certain linear transformation...

Comment: How do **you** define the derivative of a function $\;T:\mathcal C[0,1]\to\mathcal C[0,1]\;$ ? I can't seem to continue on this without knowing this first.

Comment: In this case I define $T'$ to be the derivative of $T$ at $y_0 \in C[0,1]$ if $\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall y \in C[0,1]$, $||y-y_0||_\infty < \delta$ implies $\frac{||T(y) - T(y_0) - T'(y-y_0)||_\infty}{||y-y_0||_\infty} < \varepsilon$

Comment: @VladimirNabokov Can you then write down explicitly $T_f(y) - T_f(x) - nx^{n-1} y$ for $f = x^n$?

Answer (score 0):

$T_f(y+h)(t)-T_f(y)(t)-f'(x)y(t)=f(y+h)(t)-f(y(t))-f'(x)(y(t))=O(h(t))$ since the derivative of $f$ is $f'$.

This implies that

$\|T_f(y+h)(t)-T_f(y)(t)-f'(x)y(t)\|=Sup_{|t\in [0,1]}|O(h(t)|=O(h)$